# How to get all the columns name of a DB table in SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

I am new to SilverStripe and I want to perform a simple query using SilverStripe functions (I don't want to use raw SQL). I want to get all the columns' names of the product table.
So far, I didn't find anything useful in the SilverStripe documentation. I appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that the Silverstripe `$db` (Data Model / ORM) and database columns are not always in sync. If you delete a `$db` attribute, the column will still exist in your database, but no longer in your ORM. [Source](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/model/data_model_and_orm/)

Assuming you want the current ORM-attributes, you can simply use, for a Dataobject `$record`:

```
$attributes = $record->toMap();
```

Even more attributes (even inherited attributes) can be collected by using the schema:

```
$schema = \SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject::getSchema();
$allFields = $schema->fieldSpecs($record);
$columns = array_keys($allFields);
```